# Fix color of WordPress icon in iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

Just started using the iOS app and noticed that the icon for https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ is dark gray on slightly darker gray.

[image: hf]

- App Version: 1.4.3.7
- Device: Unknown (iPad5,1)
- OS Version: Version 9.2.1 (Build 13D15)